# Why is there no compilation error with those array declarations (C89-C90)?

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, compilation, c89

I want to show that arrays can't be defined with a variable for the length in C89 or C90.

I use GCC on Windows from TDM GCC:

```
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin> .\gcc.exe --version
gcc.exe (tdm64-1) 10.3.0
```

My compilation options are:
`gcc.exe -Wall -g -ansi -save-temps  -c`

I tried:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int tab[i];

    tab[0] = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

But it compiles fine:

```
gcc.exe -Wall -g -ansi -save-temps -c main.c -o main.o
gcc.exe -o Sandbox.exe main.o  
main.c:6:9: warning: variable 'tab' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    6 |     int tab[i];
      |         ^~~
main.c:6:5: warning: 'i' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    6 |     int tab[i];
      |     ^~~
Output file is bin\Debug\Sandbox.exe with size 196.89 KB
```

Then:

```
int test(int i)
{
    int tab[i];
    tab[0] = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles too:

```
main.c: In function 'test':
main.c:5:9: warning: variable 'tab' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    5 |     int tab[i];
      |         ^~~
Output file is bin\Debug\Sandbox.exe with size 196.90 KB
```

Or:

```
int main()
{
    volatile int i;
    int tab[i];

    tab[0] = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

Only this is not compiling:

```
int main()
{
    // Comment
    return 0;
}
```

```
error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
```

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc has sloppy standard compliance per default. It defaults to lax C conformance + GNU extensions, equivalent to `-std=gnu89` (current version defaults to `-std=gnu17`).

When you type `-ansi` it does *not* mean conforming mode, but rather just the very same thing as `-std=c89`, "lax C89 mode". This compiler option may disable some GNU extensions... maybe... while keeping others. The difference between `-std=c89` and `-std=gnu89` is as poorly documented as the rest of gcc. We can [read the unfriendly manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) and it says:

> For example, -std=c90 turns off certain features of GCC that are incompatible with ISO C90, such as the asm and typeof keywords, but not other GNU extensions that do not have a meaning in ISO C90

gcc supported variable-length arrays as an extensions even before C99, so switching out the GNU option ought to disable them, but not so... As far as I know, there is no official documentation over what features `-std=c89` shuts off or at least I can't find it.

What's important to realize is that `-std=c89`/`-ansi` alone does *not* push gcc into conforming mode! To do that, you need to do `-std=c89 -pedantic` or if you will `-std=c89 -pedantic-errors`. After which you'll get a diagnostic like this:

> error: ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'tab'

And when compiling with these two options in combination, gcc probably has the best standard compliance of any compiler out there.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. After reading your answer, `-std=c89` and `-ansi` are indeed very confusing!

Comment: @Plouff: I believe the origin of `-pedantic` was that GCC author Richard Stallman thought that his extensions were awesome, and why would anyone seriously want to switch them off?  So the option that does so was made fairly obscure and given a mildly insulting name.

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree that it's a poorly chosen name. They should alias the name with `-conforming` or `-iso9899` or something like that.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Wow this is incredible! Furthermore in french pedantic is a "false-friend" for conceited... Even more insulting to me and quite in line with the story you share.

Answer (score 3):

Variable length array is a GCC extension in older standard versions. Extensions are "compatible" with the standard. If you want to exactly adhere to the standard, i.e. you want to get a message when using an extension, add `-pedantic` option (and `-pedantic-errors` for errors).

Gcc docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length , https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options .

Comment: Thanks a lot! The full list of extension is also available here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html . It's funny to see that there are extensions for a lot of stuff but not for C++ style comments :)!

Comment: @Plouff: C++ style comments have been there for a very long time, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Comments.html#C_002b_002b-Comments.  Of course since C99 this is no longer an extension, but part of the standard.